# Hide things from the past in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have several activities in my database, but I would like to hide the ones from the past, so I modified my MySQL request:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAgenda WHERE date <= CURDATE() order by date ASC";`

But it doesn't do a thing except giving errors. What's wrong?

Comment: what data type is your "data" column

Comment: did you mean to put 'date' instead of 'data'? if not, please post the errors you are getting.

Comment: @contagious, I'm sorry, it's date!

Comment: your sql query will always output older rows unless you insert them with a future date and do `>= CURDATE()` also is the date 2008-11-11 format if your using `CURDATE()`

Comment: @Brad @zod the error: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...`

Comment: that means false was returned from the query, put an `or die(mysql_error());` at end of your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not getting any results, so that is throwing errors.  You always need to check for results before looping, you cannot just assume that every query will return something.

Also, if you want things from the present/future, your comparison operand is backward:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAgenda WHERE date >= CURDATE() order by date ASC";
```

Putting it together:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblAgenda WHERE date >= CURDATE() order by date ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    // do something to handle zero results here
} else {
    // do your usual while... loop
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // code for each result row
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this was my solution :) Thanks